# Visual Studio IDE - strange suggestion ("Inline diff views")

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Sometimes my `Visual Studio IDE` tries to "help" me with this strange behavior:

[image]

(look at the red border and gray tooltip about `Tab` suggestion)

but in reality it's very annoying and I make more mistakes if I suddenly press the `Tab` button.

How can I turn off this sugestion / help of Visual studio?

Comment: It's not strange. As far as Visual Studio knows, DTO is a typo. You can add it to the list of known acronyms

Comment: Probably an extension you installed that deals with naming of these. What syntax checkers/linters do you have installed?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can you help me to turrn off this `not strange` behavior?

Comment: @epascarello I do not use any syntax checkers/linters. Waiting Visual Studio's standard functionality that's coming soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn off this strange suggestions just uncheck "Inline diff views":

[image]

**Old answer:**

It seems the problem is global. Vote here if you want Microsoft to fix it soon:

[The red AI highlighting with the arrow and tab to replace is not working correctly](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/The-red-AI-highlighting-with-the-arrow-a/10228166)

Comment: 17.4 has not been a blessed release.  The new "rollback update" feature seems to have been ab/used by team members to push risky new features.  Which is the best approach, rollback to a previous version and wait until it stabilizes a bit.